# Add constructs by topic to EFA

Tags: factor-analysis

This question is somewhat related to a previous question I asked [previously](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248132/exploratory-factor-analysis-violated-assumptions)

I have a data set that has roughly 300 people in the first set and 150 in the second. The surveys were taken at two different universities in two different countries

The survey has roughly 30 questions which themselves break down - based on previous research - into about 12 constructs

These constructs have not been used together before so for example, some of them are related to culture, some are related to work attitudes, some are related to personality and some are related to experience. The constructs one could say were developed independently of each other.

My question is

> Do I implement EFA on all the questions at once and set the number of factors I am expecting based on previous research or is it OK to just implement EFA on the related topics separately.

So for example I have four constructs that deal with just culture. Can I implement EFA on these four constructs and implement EFA separately on the other topics related constructs as well or is it good practice to implement EFA on the survey all at once?

I understand that i will have to use `CFA` in order to confirm the factors but at the moment im just exploring why some of the constructs have low `alpha` and `omega` values

Thank you for your time

Comment: `and set the number of factors I am expecting` The purpose of EFA is to set the number of factors [m] which is both (or a compromise of) best fitters of the data and most interpretable. This implies _exploration_ among several alternative `m`. If you are going to consider one predefined `m` ("expected") then why not proceed straight to CFA using some or all the paramenrs from the literature, to test if they fit the data?

Comment: As for your main question - do FA separately on subquestionnaires on once on the whole questionnaire - it depends on what is your aim. If you consider the questionnaire a _battery_ of tests, i.e. collection of unrelated - at least statistically - tests, information about correlations between items of different subquestionnaires should not bother and shouldn't be allowed to meddle; then separate factoring of each subquestionnaire is what needed.

Comment: Hi @ttnphns, Some of the constructs tend to overlap in area so i was hoping to maybe pull them apart and maybe recombine them into a single construct or split them further to simplify the modelling. In essence this is just a toy example on how to do EFA for me. I was going to use the smaller data-set to confirm the new constructs. I'm not sure if they will be better or worse but i think i can learn an awful lot by attempting it. My only concern would be if i split constructs by topic they may fail assumption tests such as `mahalanobis` for outliers

Comment: It would be possible then that the data would fail the assumptions of EFA if for example i took a five item scale separate from the whole survey. . It occurs to me since these questionnaires were not combined before. My theory is the constructs influence each other. This would suggest that the EFA should occur on the whole questionaire then? Thank you very much for your time. I will do both. Now that you mention it, it makes perfect sense

Comment: Do not be awfully preoccupied with normality. BTW, you say you have 30 items by 12 constructs. How many items in each construct are considering? If that is about 3 it is ridiculous (for practice). FA is usually done on 10+ variables. Also, a factor should in the end load decently at least 3 variables.

Comment: Hi @ttnphns, that was just for clarity more than anything else. The data was sent to me by a friend and some of the constructs only have 2 questions, some 4 some 10. Its a bit messy but is good for learning